# Media keys with VirtualBox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, drivers, media-keys

On my Windows 7 computer - my keyboard is recognized as "HID Keyboard Device" in
"Device Manager", and my media keys (Play/Pause, Mute, etc) work fine.

However if I run Windows 7 with VirtualBox, keyboard is listed as
"Standard PS/2 Keyboard" and media keys do not work.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, VirtualBox itself needs to be installed with "USB Support". I did not
choose that option when I first installed, so I had to reinstall VirtualBox.
Next, after the virtual machine is started, select

```
Devices > USB > Keyboard
```

at this point it will install the drivers. Note I had to run this step twice,
because the first time it installs on the host, then on the guest.

Few notes: after this is done, "HID Keyboard Device" will show up in Device
Manager as expected. Also until you deselect the keyboard in the devices menu,
it will only be available to the guest.